# Center a text both vertically and horizontally

Tags: css, html

In the following document, is it possible to center the inner div horizontally, or in some other way make text both V and H centered in `outer` class div?

Some constraints (sorry for not specifying it at start):
1. No fixed width should be specified, since otherwise solution is trivial;
2. No JavaScript, just pure CSS and HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>the title</title>
    <style>

        div.outer {
            /* ? */
        }

        div.inner {
            display: table-cell;
            min-height: 100px;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner">
            <p>Vertically centered text. How to center it horizontally?</p>
        </div>
    <div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
.outer {
   display: table;
   width: 100%;
}
.inner {
   display: table-cell;
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

## [*demo*](http://dabblet.com/gist/3803595)

It uses no JavaScript and it doesn't require that you fix a `width`/ `height`/ `line-height`.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a single line of text, you can use:

```
div.inner {
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

Multiple lines are trickier, as browser support comes into play. Padding by percentages in CSS can work, although I have found using jQuery to detect the div.outer size & then then creating the pad is the most reliable method.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var whitespace = $("div.outer").innerHeight() - $("div.inner").innerHeight();
  var padding = Math.round(whitespace / 2);
  $("div.inner").css({
    "padding-top": padding + "px";
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for line-height option, it's certainly useful in one line text situations.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](http://sapandiwakar.wordpress.com/2011/06/05/how-to-center-text-horizontally-and-vertically-in-a-div/) tutorial. You need to add `line-height` and `width`
 to your css to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

After googling around and searching SO for several hours, I finally got a solution for centering a div in another div both horizontally and vertically.

```
        div.parent {
          display: block;
          text-align: center;
          line-height: 300px; /* the height of parent div */
        }
        div.child {
          display: inline-block;
          vertical-align: middle;
        }
```

- It doesn't use absolute positioning, so you don't need to fix child width/height.
- It doesn't use display:table/tablecell, which is not supported in some versions of IE.
- It is a pure CSS solution, no need to write javascript even if child div is dynamically loaded.

Hope this can help people who suffer for this.